# BIOS не видит оперативную память

Tags: windows-10, bios

Ноутбук Lenovo Ideapad 310-15IKB. Разбор ноутбука не осуществлялся, плата оригинальная. Оперативную память пробовал заведомо рабочую, kingston и samsung. Bios InhydeH20 Rev. 5, не кастомный. Механические повреждения возможны, ноутбук использовался не мной. Визуальных дефектов на плате нет, на слоте оперативной памяти тоже все ок. AIDA64 и CPU-Z выводят полную информацию про дополнительную плашку, Windows и BIOS не видят, показывают только 4096 мб, как я понимаю, распаянной оперативной памяти. Оперативная память заведомо совместима с материнской платой. Windows Pro лицензия 64 разрядная. В чем может быть проблема?

### Решение

Помогла замена слота оперативной памяти.

Comment: У вас стоит 32 битная операционная система и вы упёрлись в лимит 4гб опреативки?

Answer (score 1):

Я могу предположить, что у вас кастомное обновление BIOS, либо китайская материнская плата. Так же возможно поддельный модуль памяти (что вряд ли, если распаяна на плате, предполагаю, что у вас ноутбук). Так же возможно повреждение платы / биоса. Слишком мало информации, чтобы дать развернутый ответ.

Comment: ноутбук Lenovo Ideapad 310-15IKB. Разбор ноутбука не осуществлялся, плата оригинальная. Оперативную память пробовал заведомо рабочую, kingston и samsung. Bios InhydeH20 Rev. 5, не кастомный. Механические повреждения возможны, ноутбук использовался не мной. Визуальных дефектов на плате нет, на слоте оперативной памяти тоже все ок. AIDA64 и CPU-Z выводят полную информацию про дополнительную плашку, Windows и BIOS не видят, показывают только 4096 мб, как я понимаю, распаянной оперативной памяти. Оперативная память заведомо совместима с материнской платой.

Comment: Win+R => msconfig => раздел "Загрузка" кнопка "Доп. параметры" проверь параметр "Максимум памяти"

Comment: @Yakov Максимум памяти выключен

Comment: когда memcheck("средство проверки памяти Windows" в поиске винды) запускаешь тоже не видит всю оперативу когда в PE перезагружается?

Answer (score 0):

Так бывает, когда ОС на 32 разряда. Планку будет видеть, а адресации памяти хватает максимум на 4гб. Ставьте 64-разрядную версию операционной системы. Это позволит использовать бОльшие объёмы оперативной памяти.

Comment: Про винду забыл написать. Windows Pro лицензия 64 разрядная.

Comment: @Jeimip загрузите вот эту операционную систему https://manjaro.org/downloads/official/gnome/  монжара работает с флешки без установки. Посмотрите, сколько оперативки выдаст она. и выложите весь лог, который выдаст команда `dmesg`. Это поможет делу. Если есть какие-то проблемы с железом, dmesg их как правило показывает.

Comment: скоро попробую и отпишусь. Работал с манжарой раньше.